# replacing a submitlink with indicatingAjaxButton

Tags: ajax, wicket

I have a form with a submitbutton which will get results from a database and updates a listview based on these results. If there is no result, a feedback message is shown. This all works fine.

Now I want to replace the submitlink with an IndicatingAjaxButton, so the user can see something happening when getting the result takes a long time.

The basic idea is this:

```
IndicatingAjaxButton submitLink = new IndicatingAjaxButton("submit", form) {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4306011625084297054L;

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
            Integer hourFrom = 0;
            Integer hourTo = 0;
            Integer minuteFrom = 0;
            Integer minuteTo = 0;
            hourFrom = Integer.parseInt(hour_from.getModelObject());
            hourTo = Integer.parseInt(hour_to.getModelObject());

            minuteFrom = Integer.parseInt(minute_from.getModelObject());
            minuteTo = Integer.parseInt(minute_to.getModelObject());

            Calendar from = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();

            Date dateFrom = date_from.getModelObject();
            Date dateTo = date_to.getModelObject();

            from.setTime(dateFrom);
            to.setTime(dateTo);

            from.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourFrom);
            from.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteFrom);

            to.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourTo);
            to.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteTo);

            if (topicQueueSelect.getModelObject() == null) {
                error("Please select a message name.");
                getSession().setAttribute("error", "");
            }

            if (to.before(from)) {
                error("Date to must be after date from.");
                getSession().setAttribute("error", "");
            }

            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            if (from.after(cal)) {
                error("Date from must be in the past.");
                getSession().setAttribute("error", "");
            }

            if (getSession().getAttribute("error") != null) {
                getSession().removeAttribute("error");
                return;
            }

            page.setModelObject(1);
            List<Search> searchFields = (List<Search>) searchFieldsField
                    .getModelObject();
            messageKeyDataList = messageController.search(
                    topicQueueSelect.getModelObject(), searchFields,
                    from.getTime(), to.getTime(),
                    maxResults.getModelObject(), page.getModelObject(),
                    sortorder);
            if (messageKeyDataList.size() == 0) {
                info("Search criteria didn't produce any results.");
                result.setList(messageKeyDataList);
                resultContainer.setVisible(false);
                return;
            }
            resultContainer.setVisible(true);
            resultSize = messageController.getResultSize();
            int pages = (int) Math.ceil((float) resultSize
                    / maxResults.getModelObject());
            ArrayList<Integer> pageNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int n = 1; n <= pages; n++) {
                pageNumbers.add(n);
            }
            page.setChoices(pageNumbers);
            pageunder.setChoices(pageNumbers);
            showing.setDefaultModelObject("Showing 1 to "
                    + messageKeyDataList.size() + " out of " + resultSize
                    + " messages");

            lastSearch.put("topicQueue", topicQueueSelect.getModelObject());
            lastSearch.put("searchFields", searchFields);
            lastSearch.put("from", from.getTime());
            lastSearch.put("to", to.getTime());
            lastSearch.put("maxResults", maxResults.getModelObject());
            result.setList(messageKeyDataList);
            target.add(feedback);
        }
    };
```

The SubmitLink does show me either the ResultView with the new list, or the info message, the IndicatingAjaxButton doesn't. I know the form submit is called, because the system.out is being printed.

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to do setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true) on both the resultContainer and the feedback. After that adding them to the requesttarget works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

SubmitLink is non-Ajax component. Using it will repaint the whole page!
IndicatingAjaxButton is an Ajax component. You need to use the passed AjaxRequestTarget to add components which should be repainted with the Ajax response. For example the FeedbackPanel should be added to the AjaxRequestTarget.

Comment: The resultview is part of a webmarkupcontainer named resultContainer. I already had tried target.add(resultContainer), but that had no effect.

Comment: Please update the code snippet in your question. It is hard for us to guess what could be the problem if we see dummy code.

Comment: Ok, i updated the code to which it should be. The entire code for this class is over 1200 lines so i don't think it would be wise to post it here. Can I somehow add it as an attachment?